# why can't my div have a full-browser width background color in Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, background, width

I'm creating a theme from scratch. My body has a white background and I want a div within the body to have a grey background-so that a small area of the body will have a different color (grey) background.

I've changed my div's background-color to grey but I can't get rid of the white margins on either side. Probably because my **`div.container`** has a **`max-width: 960px;`**.
 How do I get this grey div to go full browser width, with no white on either side, but still keep the body's content/text at 960px?

Comment: Simply put `body{background-color:grey;}`

Comment: @Rohil He wants only the div inside the body to be grey not the whole body

Comment: May be I misunderstood the question in hurry. Sorry for that ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an outer div before your div.container

```
<div class="outer-div">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</div>
```

In your css

```
.outer-div {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in the css for the body tag, where it is more than likely has `width: 960px;`, so changing the body background will not change the full width background.

So to change the full width background you will need to change the html tag's css.

html
{
    background: #yourcolor;
}